# Why is my Azure WebJobs "settings.job" file being ignored?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

When Azure WebJobs are stopped or restarted for whatever reason, there is a default grace period of 5 seconds before the host console process is terminated. Apparently it is possible to increase this time period by including a "settings.job" file with the WebJob when it is published to Azure, as [explained here](https://github.com/mathewc/samples/tree/master/WebJobSamples/ContinuousJobGracefulShutdown). Unfortunately I cannot get this to work for my website, and the shutdown period is *always* 5 seconds, despite this being a continuous WebJob that is published to a Basic App Service that is set to "Always On".

As per the sample code from the link, my **Program.cs** looks like this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var host = new JobHost();
        host.RunAndBlock();
    }
}
```

and my **Functions.cs** looks like this:

```
public class Functions
{
    public static async Task ProcessQueueMessageAsync(
        [QueueTrigger("testq")] string message, TextWriter log,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Function started.");
        try
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10), cancellationToken);
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException)
        {
            Shutdown().Wait();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Function completed succesfully.");
    }

    private static async Task Shutdown()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Function has been cancelled. Performing cleanup ...");
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
        Console.WriteLine("Function was cancelled and has terminated gracefully.");
    }
}
```

I have added a **settings.job** file to the project, and in its Properties in Visual Studio I have set it to "Copy always". The content of the file is as follows:

```
{ "stopping_wait_time": 60 }
```

The WebJob is published with the website. By using the Kudu tools and going to the debug console I can verify that the "settings.job" file is being copied across to the same location as the WebJob host executable:

[image: Kudu screenshot]

However, if I look at the link `https://xxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/continuouswebjobs` the returned JSON does not include any settings at all:

```
{
    "status":"Stopped",
    "detailed_status":"f9e13c - Stopped\r\n",
    "log_url":"https://...",
    "name":"WebJobTest",
    "run_command":"WebJobTest.exe",
    "url":"https://...",
    "extra_info_url":"https://...",
    "type":"continuous",
    "error":null,
    "using_sdk":true,
    "settings":{
    }
}
```

Consequently, when I stop the WebJob from the Azure portal I end up with something like this in the logs:

```
[04/18/2016 12:53:12 > f9e13c: SYS INFO] Run script 'WebJobTest.exe' with script host - 'WindowsScriptHost'
[04/18/2016 12:53:12 > f9e13c: SYS INFO] Status changed to Running
[04/18/2016 12:53:13 > f9e13c: INFO] Found the following functions:
[04/18/2016 12:53:13 > f9e13c: INFO] WebJobTest.Functions.ProcessQueueMessageAsync
[04/18/2016 12:53:13 > f9e13c: INFO] Job host started
[04/18/2016 13:01:58 > f9e13c: INFO] Executing: 'Functions.ProcessQueueMessageAsync' - Reason: 'New queue message detected on 'testq'.'
[04/18/2016 13:01:58 > f9e13c: INFO] Function started.
[04/18/2016 13:02:47 > f9e13c: SYS INFO] Status changed to Disabling
[04/18/2016 13:02:53 > f9e13c: SYS INFO] Detected WebJob file/s were updated, refreshing WebJob
[04/18/2016 13:02:53 > f9e13c: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopping
[04/18/2016 13:02:53 > f9e13c: INFO] Function has been cancelled. Performing cleanup ...
[04/18/2016 13:02:58 > f9e13c: ERR ] Thread was being aborted.
[04/18/2016 13:02:58 > f9e13c: SYS INFO] WebJob process was aborted
[04/18/2016 13:02:58 > f9e13c: SYS INFO] Status changed to Stopped
```

Note the standard 5 second gap between "Status changed to Stopping" and "Thread was being aborted".

Why is the "settings.job" file being ignored?

Comment: For continuous jobs, I think it works differently. You need to look for WEBJOBS_SHUTDOWN_FILE http://blog.amitapple.com/post/2014/05/webjobs-graceful-shutdown/#.VxTwkI9OJPY

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34543086/continuous-webjob-stopping-wait-time-ignored

Comment: verify that the `settings.job` file is in the root of the webjob directory, you can browse to https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net/debugconsole and there to directory: `d:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\jobs\continuous\{jobname}`

Comment: should be { "stopping_wait_time": 60, "is_singleton": true } in settings.job

Comment: @DavidEbbo Similar yes, however on the other question the "stopping_wait_time" value was being detected by the Azure infrastructure whereas my value seems to be ignored.

Comment: @MehmetAras I don't think that is the case. Looking at the logs I can see "Function has been cancelled. Performing cleanup ..." appears: the issue is that I'm not being given long enough to cancel properly, not that cancellation is never detected.

Comment: @AlexChen-WX Why would the "is_singleton" property make a difference? Surely that just ensures that I only end up with a single instance of the WebJob, and wouldn't affect how long the host waits for cancellation.

Comment: @AmitApple Yes, I have verified that the "settings.job" file is being copied to that location on the server. I even opened the file just to check that it wasn't empty: it had the correct contents. Just seems like the Azure WebJob infrastructure isn't reading it.

Comment: Can you share your web app name, either directly or [indirectly](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Reporting-your-site-name-without-posting-it-publicly)? This will help us investigate. Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that your `settings.job` file has **two** sets of UTF-8 BOM, which is highly unusual and throws off the parser.

Specifically, it has the following sequence at the beginning (view using a hex editor): `EF BB BF EF BB BF`. Normally, the UTF-8 BOM is just `EF BB BF`.

What editor are you using that caused that?

In any case, once you fix that up, it should work fine.

Comment: That was it! I changed the file to remove the duplicate BOMs, redeployed the web app, and it worked as intended! Thanks very much, I never would have found that by myself.

Comment: As to how the dupe BOMs ended-up in the file in the first place: I added a new item to the project in VS (right click, Add > New Item), selected "Text File" and changed the name to "settings.job". Then I copied the contents of the file from [here](https://github.com/mathewc/samples/blob/master/WebJobSamples/ContinuousJobGracefulShutdown/settings.job), pasted them into the file, then saved it. This gives me the dupe BOMs. I think it must be a peculiarity of the web browser I'm using (Chrome) in that sometimes I get dupe BOMs when I paste the text into the file, and sometimes I don't.

Comment: Strange. I wish the editor made it more obvious that there is something funky about it. notepad actually behaved in a very peculiar way with that file, where it was showing some text in a different size, and editing was messed up.

Comment: Someone else ran into same [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/764c7776-ca87-4246-a1ea-f6253efd498b/cronscheduled-webjob-not-working?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview).

Comment: When you say you copied the content of the file from [here](https://github.com/mathewc/samples/blob/master/WebJobSamples/ContinuousJobGracefulShutdown/settings.job), do you mean that you selected the text and hit Copy directly in the browser, or that you had cloned that repo and then copied the content on your local machine?

Comment: Never mind, I just reproed it by copying straight from that page. Very strange. I'll try to figure out if it's a VS bug.

Comment: Yeah, I just selected the text with the mouse in Chrome, copied with Ctrl+C, then switched to VS and pasted with Ctrl+V. FWIW I'm using VS 2013 on Windows 7. As I said in the earlier comment it doesn't insert the dupe BOMs every time though.

Comment: I actually reproed it pasting in notepad as well, so we can't blame VS. I'd say it's actually a Chrome issue. When you copy from Chrome, if you start **exactly** on the open brace, it doesn't happen. But if you start selecting a little bit to the left of it, then it includes the BOM in the clipboard, causing the issue. In IE, I couldn't repro.

Comment: For those with this problem (I know, 2019). I didn't had the BOM issues, but I had spaces (I also copied from GitHub). So, this `{ "stopping_wait_time": 60 }` didn't work. This `{"stopping_wait_time":60}` worked. You can use the `https://xxx.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/continuouswebjobs` to check. After the change, I see the values there.